# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - How to secure JSONStore data

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I want to set a password in my JSONStore.

In [this IBM Worklight Information Center 5.0.6 article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_class_wl_jsonstore.html) it is mentioned that `usePassword(pwd)` is deprecated. Is there any other alternative way to provide password to my JSONStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same page also states that you can use [WL.JSONStore.init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_init.html) and declare a password there. If you don't declare it, it won't use a password.

The example shows:

```
var collections = {
   ...
}

var options = { 
   username: 'carlos', //default: 'jsonstore'
   password: '123' //default: no encryption
}

WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options) {
   ...
}
```

To learn how to use the JSONStore feature in Worklight, [go through the JSONStore training module and sample apps](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development).

Comment: Where do I need to add this..i mean in collectionname.js(autogenerated) or appname.js file. can u plz explain in detail

Comment: Go through the JSONStore training modules and sample apps: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development

Comment: Ya I got it and completed

Comment: the password used here is default : no encryption , then how do we encrypt the data (AES ) if required by the password or the key @IdanAdar , can you share a specific example